# Create Total index

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Is there a simple way to create a total index?

```
df                value
UK  2020-01-01    10
    2020-01-02    20
US  2020-01-01    100
    2020-01-02    200
```

Expected Output:

```
                    value
UK     2020-01-01    10
       2020-01-02    20
US     2020-01-01    30
       2020-01-02    40
Total  2020-01-01    40
       2020-01-02    60
```

```
df.loc[('Total', ""), :] = df.sum()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `sum` with add `Total` to column, then convert to index and last for correct order is used [`DataFrame.swaplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel.html):

```
df1 = df.sum(level=1).assign(df='Total').set_index('df', append=True).swaplevel(1,0)
print (df1)
                  value
df    new              
Total 2020-01-01    110
      2020-01-02    220

df = pd.concat([df, df1])
```